# How are emojis implemented?

Tags: unicode, icons, emoji, glyph

How are emojis stored and what part of unicode is being is used to transmit such data? Is there even a standard in using it across applications?

Answer (score 3):

Emoji are just characters in unicode. They have their own codes and everything.

How exactly they are displayed on your screen - it depends on the operating system and its installed fonts.

Here's a list of all emoji in unicode: [Full Emoji Chart](http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html).

[image]